# Best practice to write reusable code

Tags: makefile

What is a best practice to writing reusable code in `Makefile`s?

Suppose I have a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all task01-all task01-clean task01-run task02-all task02-clean task02-run

all: task01-all task02-all

###############################################################################
task01-all: task01-clean task01 task01-run

task01-clean:
     rm task01 task01.{exi,o} -f

task01:
    compiler task01.ext -O2 --make

task01-run:
    ./task01

###############################################################################
task02-all: task02-clean task02 task02-run

task02-clean:
    rm task02 task02.{exi,o} -f

task02:
    compiler task02.ext -O2 --make

task02-run:
    ./task02
```

Now I want to add new family of tasks (task03), and I need to copypaste whole section, make `s/02/03/` for it and add them to `.PHONY` section - it's noisy, disgusting and just not right.

How can I avoid that? Could I redefine all tasks with templates somehow to have nice mechanism for adding new task group in one line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the question is about writing re-usable code in Makefiles, I'll give an example of how to use pattern rules in GNU Make (it looks like that's what you're using since you mention the `.PHONY` target). However, if you're not using any of Make's dependency checking, it may be simpler to do this with a shell script--something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
TASKS="task01 task02 task03"

for i in $TASKS; do
    rm $i $i.ext $i.o -f;
    compiler $i.ext -O2 --make;
    ./$i;
done
```

But, to expand the principle to Make, we have another issue to tackle. Lines of the form:

```
task01-all: task01-clean task01 task01-run
```

don't tell Make in what order to build the pre-requisites--just that they all need to be done before `task01-all` gets built. Instead, each step to run should depend on the step before it. Something like this:

```
TASKS=task01-run task02-run task03-run

.PHONY: all $(TASKS) $(TASKS:run=clean)

all: $(TASKS)

$(TASKS:run=clean): %-clean:
    rm $* $*.ext $*.o -f

%: %.ext | %-clean
    compiler $< -O2 --make

$(TASKS): %-run: %
    ./$<
```

The rules with `%` are called "pattern rules", and they're a great tool to avoid re-writing the same rule multiple times for different targets. One caveat is that Make doesn't normally check pattern rules for a `.PHONY` target; we tell Make to do this explicitly by prefixing those rules with the list of targets and a second colon (e.g., `$(TASKS):`).

Since `task01-run` needs `task01` in order to work, we make `%-run` targets depend on `%`. Also, your Makefile shows that you want to run clean every time, so we make `%` depend on `%-clean`. Since `%-clean` doesn't actually produce any output, we make this an "order only" dependency--Make won't look for a time-stamp or anything, it will just run the `%-clean` rule first any time it needs to run the `%` rule. "Order only" dependencies are placed after a `|`:

```
%: %.ext | %-clean
```

It's worth mentioning that one of Make's greatest strengths is that it can save time by not repeating work that doesn't need to be repeated--i.e., it only runs a rule if the dependencies are newer than the target. So, you could leave off the dependency on `%-clean`, which would cause make to only run `compiler $< -O2 --make` if `%.ext` is newer than `%`:

```
%: %.ext
    compiler $< -O2 --make
```

You could then add a rule just to run all of the `%-clean` targets:

```
.PHONY: all $(TASKS) $(TASKS:run=clean) clean

clean: $(TASKS:run=clean)
```

Last thing: I use some special variables in the recipes. `$@` stands for the target being built. `$<` stands for the first dependency. `$*` stands for the "stem" of a pattern rule (i.e., the part matched by the `%`).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what I am looking for:

```
ALLS=task01-all task02-all
BUILDS=${ALLS:-all=-build}
CLEANS=${ALLS:-all=-clean}
RUNS=${ALLS:-all=-run}

.PHONY: all $(ALLS) $(CLEANS) $(BUILDS) $(RUNS)

all: $(ALLS)

###############################################################################
$(ALLS): $(CLEANS) $(BUILDS) $(RUNS)

$(CLEANS):
        rm ${@:-clean=} ${@:-clean=}.{ext,o} -f

$(BUILDS):
        compiler ${@:-build=}.ext -O2 --make

$(RUNS):
        ./${@:-run=}
```